# парсинг нескольких пакетов с контроллерами для создания документации

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Встал вопрос о внедрении Swagger 2 в проект, на данный момент контроллеры лежат каждый в своем пакете в общем пакете, выглядит это примерно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Swagger config имеет вид:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build().useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                    newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                    .code(500)
                    .message("500 mesage")
                    .build(),
                            new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                    .code(403)
                    .message("Forbidden!!!")
                    .build()));
}
```

на выходе получается каша из контроллеров и методов к ним
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Передавая basePackage в apis() я мог получить нечто похожее на желаемый результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос следующий:
Несколько basePackage передавать нельзя, это логично, но можно ли передать в конфиг несолько пакетов для парсинга, или аннотировать классы таким образом, чтобы на выходе получить документацию хотя бы примерно напоминающую дерево контроллеров в проекте?
Это мой первый опыт с Swagger? Поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием) Преобразовывать все контроллеры таким образом, чтобы они удовлетворяли описаниям в примерах-возможности нет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблему решил свойством группировки внутри конфига swagger

```
 @Bean
public Docket biometricApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("Biometric")
            .ignoredParameterTypes(File.class)
            .select()
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/somePath/**"))
            .build();
}
```